# How does 3 digit number combinations 0-9 algorithm work?

Tags: c, algorithm, math

```
#include<stdio.h>   
int main()
{
    int i, j, k;
    for (i = 0; i <= 7; i++)
    {
        for (j = i+1; j <= 8; j++)
        {
            for (k = j+1; k <= 9; k++)
            {
                printf("%d%d%d\n", i, j, k);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have this algorithm. It generates all 120 unique numbers. Maybe i am dumb, but i don't understand one simple thing.
If I remove +1 from both inner loops variable initialization, I will receive 720 unique combinations. With this +1 I am receiving 120, that does not repeat. So it clears out numbers so there are no numbers like 517 and 715, for example.
Can somebody explain how adding +1 to inner loops removes all different arrangements and only leaves one? Because there must be at least 6 unique sets of 120 numbers.

Comment: What are "all 120 unique numbers"?  Aren't there an infinite number of unique numbers?  Aren't there 10^3 unique 3-digit numbers?

Comment: the "+1" make your digit unique in the final number, if you don't use that "+1", u will have 000,001,011 , etc.

Comment: Please indent your code and don't post code with line numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you print the first set of digits, you have:

```
i j k --> i i+1 j+1 --> i i+1 i+2 --> 0 1 2,
```

and after the first completion of the `k`-loop you have:

```
i j k --> 0 1 9.
```

Then the `j`-loop is continued, with:

```
i j k --> 0 2 3.
```

If the initial values of the `j`- and `k`- loops were not incremented, then you would have:

```
i j k --> i i i --> 0 0 0
....
i j k --> 0 0 9
i j k --> 0 1 1,
```

and the sets would contain duplicate digits.

The algorithm gets all of the sets of three unique digits because it finds first all such sets that begin with `0 1`, and then all such sets that begin with `0 2`, ..., and then all such sets that begin with `1 2`, ..., and finally all such sets that begin with `7 8`, of which there is only one: `7 8 9`.

The limits placed on `i`, `j`, and `k` play a role in this. The last set will be `7 8 9`, so `i` is limited to a maximum value of 7, `j` is limited to 8, and `k` is limited to 9. When the `i`-loop is first continued:

```
i j k --> 0 8 9
i j k --> 1 2 3
```

There are no more unique sets that begin with `0 8`, and there are no unique sets that begin with `0 9` (we already have `0 1 9`, ..., `0 8 9`, justifying the limit that `j <= 8`), so now we have all unique sets that begin with `0`, and begin to find all unique sets that begin with `1`. The first of these is:

```
i j k --> i i+1 i+2 --> 1 2 3.
```

### Systematic Counting

I think that it is a mistake to think of what is happening here as "getting rid of duplicates" or some kind of sorting. This is about systematic counting. We want to count the number of unique sets of three digits. The sets `1 2 3`, `3 2 1`, and `1 3 2` are equivalent, since they contain the same members, so we don't want to list all three, but just one of these. These sets of digits contain no duplicates, i.e., `1 1 2` is not a set in this context. We are free to choose a convenient criterion for choosing which sets we will count, and we choose to count the (ordered) sets with the digits in ascending order. Note that we do not sort these, we simply count them.

The strategy employed is to list the combinations as if they were three-digit numbers, from smallest to largest. Naturally, the listing begins with the smallest possibility, `0 1 2`. Observe that the smallest such "number" that begins with the digit `d` is `d d+1 d+2`, and that the largest such "number" is `d 8 9`. The largest of all such "numbers" is `7 8 9`. These observations provide us with the limits for our loop conditions.

Think of this triple of digits as a counter. We can list all ascending three-digit "numbers" by stepping through the allowable combinations systematically. The reason for the `+1` is that we have chosen to count the "numbers" with digits in ascending order. We could just as well have chosen to count the "numbers" with digits in descending order.

Come to think of it, this might be a good exercise for you: modify your algorithm to display the digits in descending order. This might help solidify your understanding.

Comment: Yes, but this +1 does next thing. First, you have 8 numbers from 012 to 019, then 7, then 6 and till it reaches 1 number in the last 10th before switching to the next 100th. And in each descent, it skips numbers. So in the 20th it skips the first number in 30th first and second etc.Why des this pattern produces unique 120 set?

Comment: @DeadBigHead-- I have added to my answer in an attempt to address your concern.

Comment: @DeadBigHead-- I had a couple of mislabeled `i, j, k`s in my discussion of the transition from `0 8 9` to `1 2 3`. Fixed.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for.

Comment: @DeadBigHead-- Of course. I hope that this is clearer now; I find that this sort of thing is easier to explain in person, where I can gauge what is working and what is not. Sometimes it takes longer to get there with text-only interactions!

Comment: Yes, you are right. I found that the simpler the answer that you are giving - the closer you are to the core of the question. I didn't know about Systematic Counting, so it was hard to me explain what I don't understand. Thanks to you, now I know what to learn. And I will make this algorithm backwards :)

Answer (score 1):

You just get one set of those numbers, those which have digits in ascending order. becasue you start with `012`and then start incrementing the last digit till `019` and continue with `023`. The `+1` increases the next digit by one so it won't be the same. If you don't use it you would start at 000 and count up to 789 excluding all "nineties".

edit in regard to the comment:

In the generated numbers all your digits are in ascending order. So the last is always bigger than the other two.
So if you start with `012` and start increasing you get all numbers that contain a `01` then all with `02` and so forth. Until you have all possibilities with 0 then you go to `123` this way there are no duplicates.

Comment: I understand this. But why +1 gives exactly one of this sets without mistakes?

Comment: The range for i, j and k are the same (i : [0..7]=[0..(9-2)]), (j : [1..8]=[(0+1)..(9-1)]) and (k : [2..9]=[(0+2)..(9-0)]). Because i < j(=i+1) < k(=j+1), you can never generate a 3 digits having two digits identical and the i loop provide a series starting by a digit always different.

Answer (score 0):

I dug up a little bit more. And found next things:

We have 1000 3 digit numbers:

> 000-999

There are 720 possible 3 digit combinations, using the numbers 0-9:

> 10x9x8 = 720 combinations

There are 6 possible ways of arranging the 3 digits numbers:

> 3x2x1 = 6

This mean that there are duplicates in 720 numbers. For example, these set of numbers, from 720 combinations, are considered as duplicates:

> 157, 175, 517, 571, 715, 751

**The goal is to get rid of duplicates with nested loops.**

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int i, j, k;

    i = 0;
    while (i <= 9)
    {
        j = i + 1;
        while (j <= 9)
        {
            k = j + 1;
            while(k <= 9)
            {
                printf("%d%d%d\n", i, j, k);
                k++;
            }
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

If you replace +1 with 0, like this:

```
j = i + 1; with j = 0;
```

and

```
k = j + 1; k = 0;
```

You will generate all 1000 numbers.

If you additionally, put an if statement in the innermost loop:

```
while(k <= 9)
{
    if(i != j && i != k && j != k)
    {
        printf("%d%d%d\n", i, j, k);
    }
    k++;
}
```

Then you will receive 720 combinations.

But with these +1, we are getting descending order sort.
Which goes like this:

```
012, 013, 014, 015, 016, 017, 018, 019
023, 024, 025, 026, 027, 028, 029
034, 035, 036, 037, 038, 039
045, 046, 047, 048, 049
056, 057, 058, 059
067, 068, 069
078, 079
089
```

And after inner loop ends it will go again starting with 123.

So, if I understand this correctly what this +1 does, is descend sort numbers.

Because we start from 0 we are generating 8 numbers in the first line. And with each loop cycle, we are receiving one number less wich each consecutive total loops pass.

And this gives us some math magic, that gets rid of all duplicates :)

**Basically, because we are generating number and number +1 we will always receive unique numbers.**

Comment: @Scott Hunter, this was what I meant by unique combinations.

Comment: @DeadBigHead-- The main thing is that you understand what is happening in a way that works for you. That said, there is no actual sorting happening here,  no descent into a list of numbers, and no removal of numbers from an existing list. There is only the systematic generation of a list of "numbers", which are really sets. This falls under the heading of something called "systematic counting". Mathematicians, especially combinatorists, do a lot of this. I have added to my answer to discuss this a little more.